# Increase width of single page in wordpress template

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am using a full-width template from the Sela theme (https://wordpress.org/themes/sela/). I would like to increase the width of the full-width template on one specific page to the same length as the navigation bar.
http://www.somarunners.com/routes/

That is the page I would like to modify.

Using information on the web, I added the following to my css:

.page-template-full-width-page .content-wrapper.full-width.without-featured-image {
margin: 0;
}

But that did not have the intended effect.

If anyone has suggestions as to how to modify to width of the template, I would appreciate it.

Comment: u want that thing turn into full width?

Comment: If I understand you have to change the max-width in `.site` div, only for a specific page:  `.page-id-8 .site{ max-width: 100%;}`

Comment: I added what blonfu said to my custom css, and the page looks a little wider, but it's not totally full-width: http://www.somarunners.com/routes/

Answer (score 0):

you have media queries affecting your page template

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1180px)
.site {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 1180px;
    padding: 0;
}
```

A simple change in max-width will allow the changes you want made

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1180px)
.site {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

I would suggest

A) creating a custom page template and setting .site to 100% from there if it is just the one page you need changing.

Also bear in mind that changing the max-width to 100% inside the media queries may not work on larger screens.

Comment: I made this change but it only changed the layout of the front page, not the full-width page specified in my OP.